# how to use a map function to convert all negative numbers in a Data Frame to the mean of all the numbers in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

i did this but how will i get the mean of ALL the elements?

```
import pandas as pd   
import numpy as np    
df1=pd.DataFrame([[-1,2,-3,4,-4],-3,-6,-4,7,8],[-2,3,5,8,2]])    
df1=df1[df1 < 0]=df1.applymap(np.mean)    
print(df1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If convert all Dataframe to numpy values then use [`mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) with default `axis=None` for mean of all values:

```
df1[df1 < 0] = df1.to_numpy().mean()
#oldier pandas versions
#df1[df1 < 0] = df1.values.mean()
print (df1)
          0         1         2  3         4
0  1.066667  2.000000  1.066667  4  1.066667
1  1.066667  1.066667  1.066667  7  8.000000
2  1.066667  3.000000  5.000000  8  2.000000
```